# SQL Select Distinct column and latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I'm looking to select just the latest records of a table based on date, but only one one Distinct listing of each of the urls.  The table structure is like this;

```
ID        URL          DateVisited
1         google.com   01-01-2016
2         yahoo.com    01-02-2016
3         google.com   12-30-2015
4         google.com   02-01-2016
```

So for my result set I would want

```
google.com     02-01-2016
yahoo.com      01-02-2016
```

I will have a couple more conditionals in my actual query, but just want to get the single latest records in a hit log, rather than  list of distinct urls and dates, just distinct url's and the latest date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy to do using simple aggregation, like so:

```
select URL, max(DateVisited)
from <table>
group by URL
```

Comment: Worked great, I had done this, but was including the dtVisited in my group by clause giving me unwanted results, I knew it was easier than I was making it out to be!

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!

Comment: How can this be done if you also wanted the PKID for the returned rows?  Is there an equally slick method? - or do you have to muck about with row_numbers and partitions as shown in Gordon Linoff's answer?

Comment: @Geo... The trouble with returning ids, is that a URL might have multiple ids. Look at the sample data in the question. The URL `google.com` appears with 3 different IDs: 1, 3 and 4. If you're only interested in one of these, say the minimum or the maximum, you could tack on another aggregate function to the query, like `min(id)` or `max(id)`. Some SQL databases even support aggregate functions that will return arrays and comma-separated lists of all ids. Check out PostgreSQL's `array_agg()` and `string_agg()`, for instance, or MySQL's `group_concat()`. Use `count()` to count the number of ids

Answer (score 8):

This is usually done using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by url order by datevisited desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This allows you to get all the columns associated with the latest record.

Comment: As he does not need the id a vanilla max/group would suffice I think

Comment: This will return all records with group by, it should be unique by URL

Comment: @KEVALPANCHAL . . . This returns one row per `url`.

Comment: Cheers! At some point or another you'd want to join in a column which will mess up your distinctiveness if you're not doing it this way :)