# Select all columns but also by distinct column and oldest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to select rows that are distinct by `number` and are the oldest `date`.

I saw this post: [SQL Select Distinct column and latest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505558/sql-select-distinct-column-and-latest-date)

But it doesn't work in my case, because I need to select all the columns, not just the 2 that are used in the clause.

So I get this error:

> it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause` error.

Is there a way to choose all the columns, and in case there are rows with same `date`, consider the older one as the one with the lower `id`?

sample data:

```
id      name       number         date
1       foo         1111       06-11-2022
2       bar         2222       01-12-2022
3       baz         3333       12-30-2022
4      foobar       1111       02-01-2022
```

this is the query I tried:

```
SELECT id, name, number, MIN(date) as date
FROM my_table
GROUP BY number
```

using Microsoft SQL

Comment: Would you mind showing us your code and sample data, so we can reproduce the isse? Also: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: Added information, I guess this error happens because `MIN` can have more than one result if the dates are equal? In my case, I should probably get the oldest by `id` as well

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir looks like it, didn't expect the query to be so complex for that haha. I wonder if there's a way to make it simpler like the query in the link in the post. But I guess not because of the aggregate problem. Because I simply need to get the latest of each number, sounds simple, but in SQL it's not :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using `GROUP BY` aggregate function, you can only use the aggregated columns in your `SELECT` list. You can achieve your expected output in several ways, Here is one using windowed aggregate function :

```
select T.*
from (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by number order by [date], id) as sn
      from my_table
     ) T
where sn = 1;
```

[SQL here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/275506/2)