Select distinct column and latest on created_at and attach has many
How can I:

list the latest rooms_message on room
with discussions_messages.text (from discussions_messages)
and discussions_replies.replies (belongsTo discussions_messages) (from discussions_replies)?

I read many post (SQL select only rows with max value on a column or https://stackoverflow.com/a/38505618) but it's not the same problem : I can get the latest but I d'ont have the good matching id on latest. I explain it :
I have 3 tables :
rooms_messages



id
room_uuid
discussion_message_uuid
created_at




1
10
101
2024-07-16 12:30:45


2
20
102
2024-07-16 12:30:50


3
10
103
2024-07-16 12:32:45


4
20
104
2024-07-16 12:34:50


5
20
105
2024-07-16 12:36:50



discussions_messages



id
text




101
Hello


102
Test


103
Ok


104
Wow


105
Hello2



discussions_replies



id
discussion_message_uuid
text




201
101
Hello


202
101
Test


203
102
Ok


204
102
Wow



I use this request from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38505618, and it works to list the room_messages by created_at order by. But I don't have the correct rooms_messages.uuid:
select URL, max(DateVisited)
from <table>
group by URL

My query:
SELECT rm.uuid as uuid, max(rm.created_at) as created_at, rm.room_uuid as room_uuid, rm.discussion_message_uuid as discussion_message_uuid, dm.text, count(dm.uuid) as replies,
FROM rooms_messages AS rm
INNER JOIN discussions_messages AS dm ON rm.discussion_message_uuid  = dm.uuid
LEFT OUTER JOIN discussions_replies AS dr ON dm.uuid = dr.discussion_message_uuid
GROUP BY room_uuid

But I have 3 problems :

The rm.uuid isn't correct : it's not the latest
Consequence: the dm.text isn't the latest because the rm.uuid isn't the last
Consequence: I don't load the replies


Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Your current query is invalid, and would not even run on MySQL with the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY flag enabled (which it should be).  We can use ROW_NUMBER() here for a proper solution:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT rm.uuid as uuid, rm.created_at, rm.room_uuid,
           rm.discussion_message_uuid, dm.text,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rm.room_uuid ORDER BY rm.created_at DESC) rn
    FROM rooms_messages AS rm
    INNER JOIN discussions_messages AS dm ON rm.discussion_message_uuid = dm.uuid
    LEFT JOIN discussions_replies AS dr ON dm.uuid = dr.discussion_message_uuid
)

SELECT uuid, created_at, room_uuid, discussion_message_uuid, text
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;


Thank you so much @Tim for your answer! Very useful! It's like better, but I don't see the replies attach on discussions_messages

The ORDER BY rm. created_at DESC isn't working
